# regex to find the image name and extension from this url

Tags: php, regex

I have this url which is generated automatically.

```
uploads/1/0/1/7/10178123/4320885_orig.png
```

I need to get the name and the extension of the image from this url which in this case is 4320885_orig.png

i am not being able to write a regex to find the name and extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to check php's [Basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function instead of using regex

```
echo basename("uploads/1/0/1/7/10178123/4320885_orig.png");

//result: 4320885_orig.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex, use `pathinfo`...

```
echo pathinfo('uploads/1/0/1/7/10178123/4320885_orig.png', PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pathinfo()`:

```
$path = 'uploads/1/0/1/7/10178123/4320885_orig.png';

echo pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME); //png
```

You can get other components of the path as well:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($path);

echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n"; //png
echo $path_parts['dirname'],   "\n"; //uploads/1/0/1/7/10178123
echo $path_parts['basename'],  "\n"; //4320885_orig.png
echo $path_parts['filename'],  "\n"; //4320885_orig
```

See the [PHP documentation on `pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for more information.